# headings in HTML render incorrectly from R script using `rmarkdown::render`

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

When I render an HTML directly from an R script using `rmarkdown::render`function, the headings do not render as headings, if some text (but not code) is present in between two headings.

Specifically, using file test.R, containing the following code:

`````
#' ---
#' title: "Test"
#' author: "Tester"
#' date: "`r Sys.time()`"
#' output: 
#' html_document
#' ---

#+ r setup, include=FALSE 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, cache = FALSE)

#'***  

#' # Heading TEST 1
#' Just some text.

#'***

#' # Heading TEST 2  
#' Just some text.    

#' # Heading TEST 3
#' ````
#' Just some code   
#' ```` 

#'***

#' # Heading TEST 4  

#' # Heading TEST 5
#'***
`````

and running

```
require(rmarkdown)
rmarkdown::render('test.R)
```

gives:

[image: Rendered HTML output]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an empty line below the text part using `'#`  fixes the issue.

```
#' # Heading TEST 1
#' Just some text.
#'
```

[image]